# Firebase Uncaught [object Object] when uploading to Storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

When I am uploading an image as a blob to Firebase Storage I get an Uncaught [object Object] error in Firefox and Chrome but not in Edge. When I use the code example below which is pulled from the Firebase site I get the error. Says the state is running and the progress is 0%.
It was working last night and any changes have been reverted to the working version.

```
var uploadImg = storage.ref().child('images/' + user.uid + '/savedProducts/blah').put(savedImg);
                uploadImg.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, // or 'state_changed'
                function(snapshot) {
                    // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
                    var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                    console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
                    switch (snapshot.state) {
                        case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
                            console.log('Upload is paused');
                            break;
                        case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
                            console.log('Upload is running');
                            break;
                    }
                },
                function (error) {
                    switch (error.code) {
                        case 'storage/unauthorized':
                            // User doesn't have permission to access the object
                            break;

                        case 'storage/canceled':
                            // User canceled the upload
                            break;

                    case 'storage/unknown':
                    // Unknown error occurred, inspect error.serverResponse
                    break;
                    }
                },
                function () {
                    // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
                    var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
                });
```

Comment: This thread is very old. But Today I faced same problem and solved it by adding a folder before file. It means I was not able to store file at the root of Firebase storage. @Ian Brown check your code. The `user.uid` in your code maybe null.

Comment: Did you fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer but still. I hope this helps people out.

When you try to upload a blob to the storage, you used the method

`storage.ref().child('images/' + user.uid + '/savedProducts/blah').put(savedImg);`

In my case inorder to put the blob in firebase storage, I need to use the method `putString(saveImage, 'data_url')`. The `'data_url` is the format.

**Full Code**

`storage.ref().child('images/' + user.uid + '/savedProducts/blah').putString(saveImage, 'data_url');`